# Tailwindcss not aligning element <li> as expected with utility space-y-3

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I'm trying to build navbar component in react with tailwindCss.
I've added `space-y-2` to get spacing on y axis, for all `li` elements.
But the first li element (Home) is not getting spacing as expected.
It looks like
[image]

Why Home is behaving differently ?
Can anybody pls help

[Here is Code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8c9qGiLCXp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the browser dev tool in the future to inspect and hover on the elements to
see the problem

the answer: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aZtKENJcIw